# Setting default checked radio button using Redux Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to set a radio button to default checked using the following:

```
import { Field } from "redux-form";

<Field name={radio_name} component={renderField} type="radio" checked={true} value={val1} label="val1"/> 
<Field name={radio_name} component={renderField} type="radio" value={val2} label="val2"/>
<Field name={radio_name} component={renderField} type="radio" value={val3} label="val3"/>

const renderField = ({
    input,
    label,
    type
  }) =>
    (
      <div>
          <input {...input} type={type}/>
          <label>{label}</label>
      </div>
    );
```

However, there's no `checked` property in the resulting element. Anyone know why?

Comment: and how `Field` looks like...?

Comment: @DennisVash `Field` is `import { Field } from "redux-form"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use the `checked` prop:

```js
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, checked }) => (
  <div>
    <input {...input} type={type} checked={checked} />
    <label>{label}</label>
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit Redux Form - Simple Example]